# kotlin onclick callback invocation differences

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick

```
tarSign.setOnClickListener {
               
                Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(
                    R.id.action_listFragment_to_detailFragment,
                    fragmentBundle
                )
            }
```

```
 starSign.setOnClickListener(
                Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(
                    R.id.action_listFragment_to_detailFragment,
                    fragmentBundle
                )
            )
```

Please tell me what is the difference b/w these two

I was expecting them to work the same way

Answer (score 0):

In the first one, you have created a listener that calls `Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener` and then does nothing with the returned listener. The code inside the `{ }` is your listener code that is called each time the button is clicked. So, when the button is clicked, it creates an unused navigation listener, basically accomplishing nothing.

In the second one, you are first (immediately) calling `Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener` and passing that created listener to the button. So, the button's click listener is the navigation listener you have created.

Read about [Kotlin trailing lambda syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas).

Comment: how do i use the returned listener using first case code

Comment: should i use .invoke() on it

Comment: @ChaitanyaPindiprolu use second code. First one is incorrect because it creates new objects on every click which is not what you wanna do even if you theoretically can forcefully call its onclick method.

Comment: The first way + `invoke()` might work, but it is convoluted and wasteful (it creates a new listener instance to call one time every time it's clicked). Your second way is correct.